# Find the Maxima of $g(x)= xe^{x^{2}} + e^{-x^{2}}$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus

Find the Maxima of $g(x)= xe^{x^{2}} + e^{-x^{2}}$ in $[0,1]$

$g'(x) = 2x^{2} e^{x^{2}} +e^{x^{2}} -2xe^{-x^{2}}$.

I'm not able to determine the nature of $g'$.

How can I get to know about the monotonicity of $g$ from this$?$ I calculated $g''$ but that doesn't help.

Any idea$?$

Comment: IF $g'(x)=0$ then $\frac{2x}{1+2x^2}=e^{2x^2}$ that there is no answer in [0,1] for this equation. So the critical points are 0,1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x \in [0,1]$, $e^{2x^2} \geq 1$, so:
\begin{align*}
g'(x) &= e^{-x^2}((2x^2 + 1)e^{2x^2} - 2x) \\ 
&\geq e^{-x^2}(2x^2 + 1 - 2x) \\
&= e^{-x^2}(x^2 + (x - 1)^2)  \\
&\geq 0
\end{align*}